# how to run a service which receives broadcast on Oreo?

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, android-8.0-oreo

so i am trying to create a battery statistics android app but neither i'm able to receive `broadcast` using `broadcastmanager` cos its not available for android oreo and nor my `service` is running on background for more than a few minutes.
my question is how do i receive battery broadcasts like plug,unplug,level..... in background on android oreo api 26+

i run the service from the activity on destroy

```
/////my service code/////
public class bservice extends Service {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    IntentFilter ifl = new IntentFilter();
    registerReceiver(bcr,new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED));
    registerReceiver(bcr,new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED));
    registerReceiver(bcr,new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
    registerReceiver(bcr,new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF));
    registerReceiver(bcr,new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON));
    registerReceiver(bcr,ifl);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
                update();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
    Log.d("msg","running in background 1");
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

private final BroadcastReceiver bcr = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        update();
        Log.d("msg","running in background 2");
    }
};

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    //unregisterReceiver(bcr);
    Log.d("msg","service destroyed");
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        startForegroundService(new Intent(this,bservice.class));
        Log.d("msg","serv restarted");
    }

}

void update()
{.......... my updating code
    updaten(pct,cc,isCharging,isCharging);

}

Notification notification;
NotificationManager notificationManager;

void updaten(float pct,float cc,boolean a,boolean ot)
{.........my notification update code

        notificationManager.notify(id, notification);

    }
}
}
```

Comment: you can go for receiver registered in Manifest with action filter

Comment: i mentioned already its android oreo so that won't help

Comment: are you still looking for solution?

Comment: nope i'm not looking anymore

Comment: @Aishikkirtaniya do you have solution for this?

Comment: nope man i didn't have any solution yet as I'm busy on a different project now.

Answer (score 0):

Use `JobIntentService` instead of `Service` and then register broadcast receiver dynamically from service.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/JobIntentService.html

Comment: can u give me a simple example project?